# Frozen horizontal width coil in old CRT monitor

Tags: hardware, apple-ii, crt-monitor

I have an old Apple IIe CRT monitor which could use a small horizontal width adjustment.  Unfortunately, as I try to rotate the hex key in the coil with a CRT adjustment tool, it doesn't want to move.  Is this a common problem that's fixable?

I think I can dig up a replacement coil from another broken CRT board if I must, but, of course, I'd rather not resort to unnecessary surgery.

That also begets another question:  Are these inductors pretty standard across old CRTs?  I see that you can buy replacements for arcade CRTs, so I wondered if such a replacement may work as well in an Applie IIe.  I suspect it's just a matter of matching coil width and number of windings roughly to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Mind to add information about the CR, like model and components? Some pictures about the screen and details mentioned would be perfect.

Comment: It's more likely to be failing capacitors. These should be much easier to replace.